# How to generate unix timestamp in Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, unix-timestamp, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am creating an ARM template to provision keyvault and it's secrets. I want to generate unix timestamp inside template and supply to `nbf` and `exp` attributes which only take integers. Can't find much pointers on this.

i am referring to microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/secrets

If no solution in ARM template then i need to use powershell to generate and pass it to template which i may not prefer unless there is no other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to generate those with ARM templates. arm templates do not have a way to work with date\time

Comment: Powershell is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is now [a function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-date#datetimetoepoch) available to generate Unix-style timestamps from an ISO-8601 format.

```
dateTimeToEpoch('2022-11-17T09:54:13Z')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `utcNow()` function to get Date/Time during deployment time. Note you can use it only in parameter's default value:

```json
"parameters" : {
    "todayUtc": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')]"
    }
}
```

See: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#utcnow)

Comment: keyvault secrets resource need an int value, not string.